# MongoDB not limiting to queried fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb query in which I am requesting for a limited number of fields. But it is still returning the entire row. Can someone help?

```
collection.find(
        { username: searchterm },
        { username: 1 }, 
        function(e, docs){
            console.log('---- DB RESULT');
            console.log(docs);
            res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json' });
            res.write( JSON.stringify({ 'docs' : docs }) );
            res.end('\n');
        }
    );
```

Comment: Which driver are you using? [`node-mongodb-native`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) will return a cursor if you call it like your example, and not a list of results.

Comment: I am in fact using the node-mongodb-native driver. is there a work around to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `node-mongodb-native` driver, this should work (provided that the number of results isn't too large, since `toArray()` reads all results into memory first before calling the callback):

```
collection.find(
  { username: searchterm },
  { username: 1 } // [ 'username' ] works too
).toArray(function(e, docs) {
  // TODO: handle error...
  console.log('---- DB RESULT');
  console.log(docs);
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json' });
  res.write( JSON.stringify({ 'docs' : docs }) );
  res.end('\n');
});
```

If you expect a lot of results, you probably want to use streaming, perhaps using [`JSONStream`](https://npmjs.org/package/JSONStream):

```
// Create a cursor stream.
var stream = coll.find(...).stream();

// Set correct Content-Type.
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

// Pipe cursor stream, convert it to JSON, and write to the client.
stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
```

(I tested this with [Express](https://npmjs.org/package/express) but I just noticed that you seem to be using plain `http`; I think it'll still work, though)

Comment: can you also please explain the limitations with the number of results? and what should i be using if i expect large number of results?

Comment: I am getting a `TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'toArray'`

Comment: @amit which version of the driver are you using? I'm using `1.3.19` (latest). I updated my answer to show how to handle large result sets.

Comment: I am using it with express too. not sure how to check the driver version.

Comment: @amit try `npm list mongodb`

Comment: @amit in that case, I think you need to post a bit more code (like your db setup and/or your entire route handler), since it works fine for me ([here is my test](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/c28a76049651bc19b8a8))